# Entity "has a" Contact or Entity "is a" Contact

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

This question came up when i was building a LOB application. And the question is from your experience, is it better to model the Contact relationship as inheritance or delegation ?
for example:
Contact: has Firstname, Lastname, Fullname, Address, Email, etc ..
A Customer has all that plus other customer specific things.
A Dealer has all that plus other dealer specific things.
A ..... has .... and .... etc
Now is it better for Customer and Dealer to derive from Contact or to have a Contact reference ?
**note:** i know this might be an argument question but i would like to know how experienced developers go around this.

Comment: Personally I would recommend the 'has' approach - a Customer may have more than one Contact and may have more data that fits the 'has' style, which leads to a more streamlined structure.

Comment: Furthermore, contact information may lack a postal address, or an e-mail address, or a phone number, etc.. If you use an "is a" approach, you can't express this well.

Comment: Waldfee, Tinctorius, although i found both of you comments logical and they are what i did, i still find Jordao's argument convincing especially that he mentioned a book that is written by one of the gods of object oriented systems.

Comment: @Sniffer - this sample is rather abstract and is considered out of  context. Do you really treat people and units as the same entity? Do you really need "an abstraction of people and organizational units" in order to expose contact details?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a book called Analysis Patterns that goes into many details on how to model this kind of structure (and many others). In the book, inheritance is used to model a base `Party` type, that later can be subclassed into the more concrete `Person` and `Organization` classes. You can find some info [here (pdf)](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/accountability.pdf).

I think inheritance is a good solution in this case because you're clearly modeling an *is-a* relationship. You just have to be careful that you don't misuse inheritance solely for code reuse.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer composition over inheritance, especially at first stages of a project. Probably in future you'd come to *Party* pattern, if that gives you a significant advantage.

(Also note that book states that *The obvious case to use Party (5) is when you have people and organizations in your model and you see common behavior*. Behavior has priority here. As soon as you are modeling data, prefer composition).

Comment: i agree with you too mikalai, that's what am doing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Simply a customer *is not* a type of contact according to the acknowledged interpretation of these two words.

You wouldn't model a file and a person using inheritance simply because they share the fact they both have a name. It could make sense though in some (odd) domain that they both inherit from a common "NamedThing" interface.

Summarising, I'd go for "has a" in most cases but not always.

Comment: i agree with you, and as i said that's what i did, but the problem i am facing is in the financial domain similar to the problems proposed by the book mentioned above.

Comment: But if one renames contact to something more general that makes sense, such as person, then customer is type of person. It is not a simple question and IMO your simple answer is not a good one.

Comment: Then in that case you are modelling a person that is something different from a contact. In most cases person will contain a contact. Names matter as they convey some intuitive information on the responsibilities of a certain class.